# Error message: .htm "value" does not exist in current working directory, yet is it part of my webscraping dataframe

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am aware that this might be a naive question with an easy solution.

Basic web-scraping exercise, everything is in my df and structured as well. as you can see from the code below

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


#load webpage
pres.library <- read_html(x = "http://stateoftheunion.onetwothree.net/texts/index.html")

#get URL of links
links <- pres.library %>%
  html_nodes("#text li a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

#get link text
text <- pres.library %>%
  html_nodes("#text li a") %>%
  html_text()

#combine into df, add structure 
sotu <- data.frame (text = text, links = links, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  separate(text, c("President", "Date", "Year"), ",")

#check for unneccesary whitespaces
sotu$President <- trimws(sotu$President)
sotu$links <- trimws(sotu$links)
sotu$Date <- trimws(sotu$Date)
sotu$Year <- trimws(sotu$Year)

#remove data from pre-modern era
sotu.modern <- sotu[-c(1:156),]

#separate democrats from republicans
democrats <- c("Harry S. Truman", "John F. Kennedy", "Lyndon B. Johnson", "Jimmy Carter", "William J. Clinton", "Barack Obama")
sotu.modern$Party <- ifelse(sotu.modern$President %in% democrats, "Democrat", "Republican")
```

everything works fine up until here. The code here is used to extract the text from each link into the directory

```
for (i in seq(nrow(sotu.modern))) {
  sotu.text <- read_html(sotu.modern$links[i]) %>%
    html_nodes("#text li a") %>% 
    html_text()
  filename <- paste0("SOTU", President,"-", Date, Year, ".txt")
  sink(file = filename) %>%
    cat(text) %>%
    sink()
}
```

Running the code above gives me this error message:

```
'19460121.html' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/User/Desktop/R/R Projects/SOTU project')
```

"19460121.html" is the first element of the sotu.modern$link column, so I don't understand why it says that it's not in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You suply un-complete URL into `read_html`.
For example, in the first iteration it was pointed to `20200204.html`, instead of full URL `http://stateoftheunion.onetwothree.net/texts/20200204.html`

I also fix `html_node` and `filename`.

```
for (i in seq(nrow(sotu.modern))) {
  sotu.text <- read_html(paste0("http://stateoftheunion.onetwothree.net/texts/",sotu.modern$links[i])) %>%
    html_nodes("#text") %>% 
    html_text()

  filename <- paste0("SOTU", sotu.modern$President[i],"-", sotu.modern$Date[i], sotu.modern$Year[i], ".txt")
  cat(sotu.text, file=filename)
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. I feel like I was so close yet so, so far.
Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome. It look like you suply not appropiate html_node and file name. I just updated my answer.